# google calender api email notification issue

Tags: angularjs

i am using google calendar api for sending invitation but there is an issue while using google calendar api, popup notification is coming but email notification is not going nether email reminder notification.

i am using below code.

```
var request = gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json',
              'method': 'POST',
              'headers': {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getitem 
              },
              "sendNotifications": true,
              'body': JSON.stringify({
                "summary": this.calendarEvent.name,
                "location": this.calendarEvent.location,
                "description": this.calendarEvent.description,
                "start": {
                  "dateTime": startDateTimeISO,
                  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata" 
                },
                "end": {
                  "dateTime": enddateTimeISO,
                  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata" 
                },
                "recurrence": [
                  "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1" 
                ],
                "attendees": "...@gmail.com",
                "reminders": {
                  "useDefault": false,
                  "overrides": [
                    {
                      "method": "email",
                      "minutes": 1440       
                    },
                    {
                      "method": "popup",
                      "minutes": 10         
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
```

Comment: please post your error trace

Comment: error is not coming, event is also added in google calendar only email notification is not going to attendees.